# Angularjs tooltip show data

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs and trying to use the bootstrap-ui tooltip.
I have to show the description on hover over code. but the tooltip doesnt display actual data.

What am I missing?

```html
<a href="#" class="aCustom" e-style="width:100px" title="{{item.Description}}" data-toggle="tooltip">
{{item.Code}}
  </a>
```

Comment: Share all relevant code and error you're getting in console

Comment: It shows to me, maybe item.Description it is not initialized in your code. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: your html code work for me. did you set your variable in the scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html code work for me. did you set your variable in the scope ?

```
 test.controller('testCtrl', ["$scope",  function ( $scope) {         
     $scope.item= { "Description" : 'the super description', "Code" : "1234"     };
 }]);
```